# Angular Unit Tests Failing in GitLab Pipeline

Tags: angular, jestjs, gitlab, gitlab-ci

We have unit tests that are suddenly failing in our GitLab pipeline. These tests were running successfully last week, and no code changes have been made to affect them. On top of that, these tests run fine locally. We're using jest as our test runner with ts-jest, and we're getting the following error for all of our tests that call HttpTestingController.expectOne().

Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL: "baseUrl/object/arg1/object2/arg2"

```js
const myUrl = `baseUrl/object/${arg1}/object2/${arg2}`;
myService.callPostMethod(arg1, arg2).subscribe((result) => {
  expect(result).toBe(datum.expected);
});
let req = httpTestingController.expectOne(myUrl); // Fails here
```

Outside of code changes, are there any possible things that may have introduced this issue? Our dependencies are cached in Nexus daily and installed from there. We're using Angular 8.2.14 and the latest patch of Jest 26.

Comment: Update: We've determined that this is due to a breaking change published for tough-cookie. See issue here: https://github.com/salesforce/tough-cookie/issues/246

Answer (score 0):

Do the test be executed in some container or gitlab-runner directly? Have you checked if in your gitlab-runner versions of npm/node have not been changed?